# DrmSession$DrmSessionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to restore keys: BAD_VALUE

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, samsung-mobile

**DrmSession$DrmSessionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to restore keys: BAD_VALUE** occurs when trying to play downloaded content offline using the ExoPlayer library version 2.18.2.

Log attached. If you need to provide additional information about the implementation or other logs, I will be happy to help resolve the issue.

The problem is compounded by the fact that the bug only reproduces on Samsung S23 / S23 Ultra devices, but does not reproduce on other real devices and on emulators.

Ideas, hypotheses, assumptions?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

```
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSession$DrmSessionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to restore keys: BAD_VALUE
============================== Beginning of DRM Plugin Log ==============================
  06-05 17:35:02.306 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(943):Initialize] Level 1 Build Info (v17): Build Information: API_Version: 17.0 LibOEMCrypto_Version: 1.63 TA_Version: 1.12
  06-05 17:35:02.308 I [usage_table_header.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
  06-05 17:35:02.311 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid17
  06-05 17:35:02.311 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid17
  06-05 17:35:02.312 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid17, playback_id = eHNgqF5yFHXTlMPq
  06-05 17:35:02.315 I [cdm_engine.cpp(274):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid17, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Streaming
  06-05 17:35:02.345 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:35:02.345 I [cdm_engine.cpp(888):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid17
  06-05 17:35:02.388 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:35:02.792 I [cdm_engine.cpp(353):AddKey] session_id = sid17, key_set_id = <empty>
  06-05 17:35:13.375 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid18
  06-05 17:35:13.375 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid18
  06-05 17:35:13.376 I [cdm_engine.cpp(274):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid18, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Offline
  06-05 17:35:13.481 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid19
  06-05 17:35:13.481 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid19
  06-05 17:35:13.482 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid19, playback_id = OqJpprUlvFI7YWWb
  06-05 17:35:13.483 I [cdm_engine.cpp(274):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid19, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Streaming
  06-05 17:35:13.509 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:35:13.509 I [cdm_engine.cpp(888):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid19
  06-05 17:35:13.553 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:35:13.586 I [cdm_engine.cpp(353):AddKey] session_id = sid18, key_set_id = <empty>
  06-05 17:35:13.625 I [cdm_engine.cpp(421):AddKey] key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 17:35:13.626 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid18
  06-05 17:35:13.876 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid17
  06-05 17:35:14.337 I [cdm_engine.cpp(353):AddKey] session_id = sid19, key_set_id = <empty>
  06-05 17:35:39.761 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid19
  06-05 17:35:39.764 E [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(955):Level1Terminate] L1 Terminate
  06-05 17:35:39.764 I [(0):] L3 Terminate.
  06-05 17:36:01.524 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(900):Initialize] Level 3 Build Info (v17): OEMCrypto Level3 Code May 20 2022 21:36:54
  06-05 17:36:01.525 I [(0):] Level3 Library 22594 May 20 2022 21:36:54
  06-05 17:36:01.527 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(914):Initialize] L3 Initialized. Trying L1.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1137):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc113.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1140):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc124.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1134):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc119.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1131):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc116.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1110):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc23.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(943):Initialize] Level 1 Build Info (v17): Build Information: API_Version: 17.0 LibOEMCrypto_Version: 1.63 TA_Version: 1.12
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1145):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc129.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1132):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc117.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1139):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc123.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1138):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc114.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1068):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc90.
  06-05 17:36:01.609 I [usage_table_header.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
  06-05 17:36:01.612 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid20
  06-05 17:36:01.612 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid20
  06-05 17:36:01.613 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid20, playback_id = v8AcsXDUlZXd54CD
  06-05 17:36:01.614 I [cdm_engine.cpp(274):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid20, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Streaming
  06-05 17:36:01.640 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:36:01.641 I [cdm_engine.cpp(888):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid20
  06-05 17:36:01.679 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:36:01.947 I [cdm_engine.cpp(353):AddKey] session_id = sid20, key_set_id = <empty>
  06-05 17:38:14.449 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid20
  06-05 17:48:28.436 I [usage_table_header.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
  06-05 17:48:28.480 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid21
  06-05 17:48:28.480 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid21
  06-05 17:48:28.481 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid21, playback_id = 5x6cqvJgBZQvfF-O
  06-05 17:48:28.482 I [cdm_engine.cpp(445):RestoreKey] session_id = sid21, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 17:48:28.482 E [device_files.cpp(876):RetrieveLicense] Unable to retrieve key set license file: result = NotFound
  06-05 17:48:28.482 E [cdm_session.cpp(236):RestoreOfflineSession] Failed to retrieve license: sub_error_code = NotFound, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 17:48:28.482 E [cdm_engine.cpp(464):RestoreKey] Restore offline session failed: session_id = sid21, status = 347
  06-05 17:48:28.482 W [device_files.cpp(1989):RetrieveHashedFile] File does not exist: path = /data/vendor/mediadrm/IDM1013/L1/ksidB78129D7.lic
  06-05 17:48:28.490 I [cdm_engine.cpp(888):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid21
  06-05 17:48:28.490 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:48:28.571 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid21
  06-05 17:48:38.938 I [(0):] L3 Terminate.
  06-05 17:48:38.938 E [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(955):Level1Terminate] L1 Terminate
  06-05 19:03:35.378 I No hidl drm factories found
  06-05 19:03:35.379 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
  06-05 19:03:36.734 I No hidl drm factories found
  06-05 19:03:36.734 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
  06-05 19:03:36.748 I No hidl drm factories found
  06-05 19:03:36.749 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
  06-05 19:03:36.771 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(900):Initialize] Level 3 Build Info (v17): OEMCrypto Level3 Code May 20 2022 21:36:54
  06-05 19:03:36.771 I [(0):] Level3 Library 22594 May 20 2022 21:36:54
  06-05 19:03:36.779 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(914):Initialize] L3 Initialized. Trying L1.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1134):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc119.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1138):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc114.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1140):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc124.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1145):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc129.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1068):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc90.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1110):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc23.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1131):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc116.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1132):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc117.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1139):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc123.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1137):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc113.
  06-05 19:03:36.844 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(943):Initialize] Level 1 Build Info (v17): Build Information: API_Version: 17.0 LibOEMCrypto_Version: 1.63 TA_Version: 1.12
  06-05 19:03:36.845 I [usage_table_header.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
  06-05 19:03:36.875 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid22
  06-05 19:03:36.875 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid22
  06-05 19:03:36.877 W [device_files.cpp(1989):RetrieveHashedFile] File does not exist: path = /data/vendor/mediadrm/IDM1013/L1/ksidB78129D7.lic
  06-05 19:03:36.877 E [cdm_engine.cpp(464):RestoreKey] Restore offline session failed: session_id = sid22, status = 347
  06-05 19:03:36.877 E [device_files.cpp(876):RetrieveLicense] Unable to retrieve key set license file: result = NotFound
  06-05 19:03:36.877 E [cdm_session.cpp(236):RestoreOfflineSession] Failed to retrieve license: sub_error_code = NotFound, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 19:03:36.877 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid22, playback_id = HhuYp6Sb4AbuAM3t
  06-05 19:03:36.877 I [cdm_engine.cpp(445):RestoreKey] session_id = sid22, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 19:03:36.881 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 19:03:36.881 I [cdm_engine.cpp(888):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid22
  06-05 19:03:36.952 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid22
  06-05 19:04:03.055 I No hidl drm factories found
  06-05 19:04:03.056 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
  06-05 19:04:03.062 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
  06-05 19:04:03.062 I No hidl drm factories found
  06-05 19:04:03.073 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid23
  06-05 19:04:03.073 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid23
  06-05 19:04:03.074 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid23, playback_id = jBUp0cQ25vTbpd3T
  06-05 19:04:03.074 I [cdm_engine.cpp(445):RestoreKey] session_id = sid23, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 19:04:03.074 W [device_files.cpp(1989):RetrieveHashedFile] File does not exist: path = /data/vendor/mediadrm/IDM1013/L1/ksidB78129D7.lic
  06-05 19:04:03.074 E [device_files.cpp(876):RetrieveLicense] Unable to retrieve key set license file: result = NotFound
  06-05 19:04:03.074 E [cdm_session.cpp(236):RestoreOfflineSession] Failed to retrieve license: sub_error_code = NotFound, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 19:04:03.074 E [cdm_engine.cpp(464):RestoreKey] Restore offline session failed: session_id = sid23, status = 347
============================== End of DRM Plugin Log ==============================
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.onError(DefaultDrmSession.java:94)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.doLicense(DefaultDrmSession.java:87)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.acquire(DefaultDrmSession.java:148)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.createAndAcquireSession(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:54)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.createAndAcquireSessionWithRetry(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:1)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.acquireSession(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:35)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager$PreacquiredSessionReference$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:24)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to restore keys: BAD_VALUE
============================== Beginning of DRM Plugin Log ==============================
  06-05 17:35:02.306 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(943):Initialize] Level 1 Build Info (v17): Build Information: API_Version: 17.0 LibOEMCrypto_Version: 1.63 TA_Version: 1.12
  06-05 17:35:02.308 I [usage_table_header.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
  06-05 17:35:02.311 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid17
  06-05 17:35:02.311 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid17
  06-05 17:35:02.312 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid17, playback_id = eHNgqF5yFHXTlMPq
  06-05 17:35:02.315 I [cdm_engine.cpp(274):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid17, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Streaming
  06-05 17:35:02.345 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:35:02.345 I [cdm_engine.cpp(888):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid17
  06-05 17:35:02.388 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:35:02.792 I [cdm_engine.cpp(353):AddKey] session_id = sid17, key_set_id = <empty>
  06-05 17:35:13.375 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid18
  06-05 17:35:13.375 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid18
  06-05 17:35:13.376 I [cdm_engine.cpp(274):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid18, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Offline
  06-05 17:35:13.481 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid19
  06-05 17:35:13.481 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid19
  06-05 17:35:13.482 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid19, playback_id = OqJpprUlvFI7YWWb
  06-05 17:35:13.483 I [cdm_engine.cpp(274):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid19, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Streaming
  06-05 17:35:13.509 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:35:13.509 I [cdm_engine.cpp(888):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid19
  06-05 17:35:13.553 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:35:13.586 I [cdm_engine.cpp(353):AddKey] session_id = sid18, key_set_id = <empty>
  06-05 17:35:13.625 I [cdm_engine.cpp(421):AddKey] key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 17:35:13.626 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid18
  06-05 17:35:13.876 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid17
  06-05 17:35:14.337 I [cdm_engine.cpp(353):AddKey] session_id = sid19, key_set_id = <empty>
  06-05 17:35:39.761 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid19
  06-05 17:35:39.764 E [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(955):Level1Terminate] L1 Terminate
  06-05 17:35:39.764 I [(0):] L3 Terminate.
  06-05 17:36:01.524 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(900):Initialize] Level 3 Build Info (v17): OEMCrypto Level3 Code May 20 2022 21:36:54
  06-05 17:36:01.525 I [(0):] Level3 Library 22594 May 20 2022 21:36:54
  06-05 17:36:01.527 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(914):Initialize] L3 Initialized. Trying L1.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1137):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc113.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1140):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc124.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1134):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc119.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1131):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc116.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1110):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc23.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(943):Initialize] Level 1 Build Info (v17): Build Information: API_Version: 17.0 LibOEMCrypto_Version: 1.63 TA_Version: 1.12
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1145):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc129.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1132):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc117.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1139):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc123.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1138):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc114.
  06-05 17:36:01.608 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1068):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc90.
  06-05 17:36:01.609 I [usage_table_header.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
  06-05 17:36:01.612 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid20
  06-05 17:36:01.612 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid20
  06-05 17:36:01.613 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid20, playback_id = v8AcsXDUlZXd54CD
  06-05 17:36:01.614 I [cdm_engine.cpp(274):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid20, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Streaming
  06-05 17:36:01.640 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:36:01.641 I [cdm_engine.cpp(888):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid20
  06-05 17:36:01.679 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:36:01.947 I [cdm_engine.cpp(353):AddKey] session_id = sid20, key_set_id = <empty>
  06-05 17:38:14.449 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid20
  06-05 17:48:28.436 I [usage_table_header.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
  06-05 17:48:28.480 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid21
  06-05 17:48:28.480 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid21
  06-05 17:48:28.481 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid21, playback_id = 5x6cqvJgBZQvfF-O
  06-05 17:48:28.482 I [cdm_engine.cpp(445):RestoreKey] session_id = sid21, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 17:48:28.482 E [device_files.cpp(876):RetrieveLicense] Unable to retrieve key set license file: result = NotFound
  06-05 17:48:28.482 E [cdm_session.cpp(236):RestoreOfflineSession] Failed to retrieve license: sub_error_code = NotFound, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 17:48:28.482 E [cdm_engine.cpp(464):RestoreKey] Restore offline session failed: session_id = sid21, status = 347
  06-05 17:48:28.482 W [device_files.cpp(1989):RetrieveHashedFile] File does not exist: path = /data/vendor/mediadrm/IDM1013/L1/ksidB78129D7.lic
  06-05 17:48:28.490 I [cdm_engine.cpp(888):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid21
  06-05 17:48:28.490 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 17:48:28.571 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid21
  06-05 17:48:38.938 I [(0):] L3 Terminate.
  06-05 17:48:38.938 E [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(955):Level1Terminate] L1 Terminate
  06-05 19:03:35.378 I No hidl drm factories found
  06-05 19:03:35.379 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
  06-05 19:03:36.734 I No hidl drm factories found
  06-05 19:03:36.734 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
  06-05 19:03:36.748 I No hidl drm factories found
  06-05 19:03:36.749 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
  06-05 19:03:36.771 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(900):Initialize] Level 3 Build Info (v17): OEMCrypto Level3 Code May 20 2022 21:36:54
  06-05 19:03:36.771 I [(0):] Level3 Library 22594 May 20 2022 21:36:54
  06-05 19:03:36.779 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(914):Initialize] L3 Initialized. Trying L1.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1134):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc119.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1138):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc114.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1140):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc124.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1145):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc129.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1068):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc90.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1110):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc23.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1131):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc116.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1132):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc117.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1139):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc123.
  06-05 19:03:36.843 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1137):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc113.
  06-05 19:03:36.844 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(943):Initialize] Level 1 Build Info (v17): Build Information: API_Version: 17.0 LibOEMCrypto_Version: 1.63 TA_Version: 1.12
  06-05 19:03:36.845 I [usage_table_header.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
  06-05 19:03:36.875 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid22
  06-05 19:03:36.875 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid22
  06-05 19:03:36.877 W [device_files.cpp(1989):RetrieveHashedFile] File does not exist: path = /data/vendor/mediadrm/IDM1013/L1/ksidB78129D7.lic
  06-05 19:03:36.877 E [cdm_engine.cpp(464):RestoreKey] Restore offline session failed: session_id = sid22, status = 347
  06-05 19:03:36.877 E [device_files.cpp(876):RetrieveLicense] Unable to retrieve key set license file: result = NotFound
  06-05 19:03:36.877 E [cdm_session.cpp(236):RestoreOfflineSession] Failed to retrieve license: sub_error_code = NotFound, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 19:03:36.877 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid22, playback_id = HhuYp6Sb4AbuAM3t
  06-05 19:03:36.877 I [cdm_engine.cpp(445):RestoreKey] session_id = sid22, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 19:03:36.881 I [cdm_engine.cpp(994):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
  06-05 19:03:36.881 I [cdm_engine.cpp(888):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid22
  06-05 19:03:36.952 I [cdm_engine.cpp(232):CloseSession] session_id = sid22
  06-05 19:04:03.055 I No hidl drm factories found
  06-05 19:04:03.056 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
  06-05 19:04:03.062 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
  06-05 19:04:03.062 I No hidl drm factories found
  06-05 19:04:03.073 I [cdm_engine.cpp(187):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid23
  06-05 19:04:03.073 I [cdm_engine.cpp(983):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid23
  06-05 19:04:03.074 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2141):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid23, playback_id = jBUp0cQ25vTbpd3T
  06-05 19:04:03.074 I [cdm_engine.cpp(445):RestoreKey] session_id = sid23, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 19:04:03.074 W [device_files.cpp(1989):RetrieveHashedFile] File does not exist: path = /data/vendor/mediadrm/IDM1013/L1/ksidB78129D7.lic
  06-05 19:04:03.074 E [device_files.cpp(876):RetrieveLicense] Unable to retrieve key set license file: result = NotFound
  06-05 19:04:03.074 E [cdm_session.cpp(236):RestoreOfflineSession] Failed to retrieve license: sub_error_code = NotFound, key_set_id = ksidB78129D7
  06-05 19:04:03.074 E [cdm_engine.cpp(464):RestoreKey] Restore offline session failed: session_id = sid23, status = 347
============================== End of DRM Plugin Log ==============================
```

I tried looking at the demo app in the ExoPlayer library and went through a lot of similar issues, but didn't find any solution given that the issues on GitHub are 4-5 years old.